# django transfer variable between html's

Tags: python, html, django, django-urls

Hi i am trying to create a search engine and i need to make the table id stay in the link.

In my CrawledTables have all the tables with the id...and i need to pass that id into the var *pk* through the links...cause then i request to get that pk and use the pk to get the table name. and then use the table name to get the data inside the table i searched for...and make a search engine inside those table info.

**Error:**

```
Reverse for 'table_search' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'search/(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']
```

This is my *views.py*

```
def search_form(request):
    return render(request, 'search/search.html')


def search(request):
    if 'q' in request.GET and request.GET['q']:
        q = request.GET['q']
        name = Crawledtables.objects.filter(name__icontains=q)
        return render(request, 'search/results.html', {'name': name, 'query': q})
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Please submit a search term.')


def search_form_table(request):
    return render(request, 'search/search_table.html', {'tbl_nm': table_name})


def search_table(request, pk):
    if 'q' in request.GET and request.GET['q']:
        q = request.GET['q']
        table_name = Crawledtables.objects.get(id=pk)
        print table_name
        t = create_model(table_name.name)
        print t
        title = t.objects.filter(title__icontains=q)
        print title
        return render(request, 'search/results_table.html', {'tbl_name': table_name,
                                                             'details': title,
                                                             'query': q})
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Please submit a search term!")
```

this is my *search/urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^results$', views.search, name='search'),
    url(r'^$', views.search_form, name='form'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.search_form_table, name='table_search'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/results$', views.search_table, name='table_results'),
]
```

this is my *search.html*

```
<form action="/search/results" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="q">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

*results.html*

```
<p> You searched for: <strong>{{ query }}</strong></p>
{% if name %}
    <p> Found {{ name|length }}</p>
    <ul>
        {% for nm in name %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'search:table_search' %}">{{ nm.name }}</a> {{ nm.date }}</li>

        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p> No results found</p>
{% endif %}
```

*search_table.html*

```
<form action="/search/{{ pk }}/results" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="q">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

*results_table.html*

```
<p> You searched for: <strong>{{ query }}</strong></p>
{% if details %}
    <p> Found {{ details|length }}</p>
    <ul>
        {% for list in details %}
            <li> {{ list.title }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p> No results found</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: What is your problem ?

Comment: The *pk* is not passing through

Comment: I did forget to post the error...i added it at the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because of `<a href="{% url 'search:table_search' %}">` in your `results.html`. Change the `href` like this.

```
{% for nm in name %}
    <li><a href="/search/{{ nm.id }}/">{{ nm.name }}</a> {{ nm.date }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```